# One pulse signal

Tags: digital-logic, shift-register

i need your suggestion about how initiate circular "1" in shift registers

Let's assume that i have two 4094 shift registers connected in series it gives 16bit shift register and clock signal.
"OS" signal from last register is connected to "D" input first register. (like a ring topology)

and the question is how intiate first cycle - how push HIGH signal only on fist cycle of clock and switch back to LOW

Answer (score 1):

You need a 4-bit counter.

You use it in a block of logic that monitors one point in your ring. If it sees 15 zeros in a row, you force the next bit to be 1.

This sounds like a homework question, so I'll leave it to you to work out the details. If you get stuck, let me know.

Of course,under the right conditions, a 15-input NOR gate works just as well, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set/reset condition to force that first bit to a one.

Answer (score 0):

i spent some time and this is acceptable sollution
[image: my solution]